# DSC Module does not implement the write property faceTime

Tags: dsc

I am not understanding the concept on how to create a Desired State Configuration Resource. I keep getting errors. I use the following. Can someone give me a very simple way to understand this?

Mof

```
[ClassVersion("1.0.0"), FriendlyName("SQLInstall")] 
class MSFT_SQLInstall: OMI_BaseResource
{
    [Key] String InstanceName;
    [Write] String SA;
    [Write, ValueMap{"Present","Absent"}, Values{"Present","Absent"}] String Ensure;
};
```

PSM1:

```
Function Get-TargetResource
{
param(
   [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
   [System.String]
   $InstanceName,

   [ValidateSet('Present','Absent')]
   [System.String]
   $Ensure    )

   $ins = @($InstanceName)
   return $ins
}

Function Set-TargetResource
{
param(
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[System.String]
$InstanceName,

[ValidateSet('Present','Absent')]
[System.String]
$Ensure    )
}
function Test-TargetResource
{
[OutputType([System.Boolean])]
param
(

[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[System.String]
$InstanceName,

[ValidateSet('Present','Absent')]
[System.String]
$Ensure
)

try {
write-verbose "Test: Getting current Instance $Instance status"
$Status = <# test goes here #>

if ($Ensure -like 'Present') 
{

  if (($Status -eq $true)) 
  {
    return $true
  } 
  else 
  {
    return $false
  }

} 
else 
{

  if ($Status -eq $true) 
  {
    return $false
  } 
  else 
  {
    return $true
  }

}
}
Catch {
$exception = $_    
Write-Verbose ("An Error Occurred: $exception.message")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DSC resource is not complete. The PSM1 must have a `Test-TargetResource` function. Whenever a DSC resource is used, the `Test-TargetResource` runs first to check if the `Set-TargetResource` should be run or not.

You need to look at writing [custom DSC resources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249927.aspx) help content on technet. Also, the [DSC resource designer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/11/19/resource-designer-tool-a-walkthrough-writing-a-dsc-resource.aspx) is a great starting point for beginners.

Comment: Thank you! I also found out that the service caches the instance running. so I added this to the bootom of my configuration file. ###
### find the Process that is hosting the DSC engine
###
$dscProcessID = Get-WmiObject msft_providers | 
Where-Object {$_.provider -like 'dsccore'} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostProcessIdentifier 

###
### Kill it
###
Get-Process -Id $dscProcessID | Stop-Process